# Event testing with Mocha and Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am new to unit tests and want to create a test that will track the inner html after a click event which will indicate the switching between two users. I have done several searches and have not been able to figure how to properly attach the unit test to the event.

Most of the resources that I have found that are similar seem to be related to React and not Vanilla Javascript. This is my front-end code:

```
const xPlayer = 'X';
const oPlayer = 'O';
const boardSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

let whosTurn = 0;
let board;

gameSetup();

function gameSetup() {
board = Array.from(Array(9).keys());
for (var i = 0; i < boardSquares.length; i++) {
    boardSquares[i].innerText = '';
    boardSquares[i].addEventListener('click', turnClick, false);
}
}

function turnClick(currentDiv) {
  if(document.getElementById(currentDiv.target.id).innerHTML === '') {
    writeInSquare(currentDiv);
  }
}

function writeInSquare(currentDiv) {
  if (whosTurn % 2 === 0) {
    document.getElementById(currentDiv.target.id).innerHTML = xPlayer;
    whosTurn++;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(currentDiv.target.id).innerHTML = oPlayer;
    whosTurn++;
  }
}

export default{
  boardSquares, whosTurn, gameSetup, turnClick, writeInSquare, checkIfGameComplete
};
```

This is my test file:

```
import sum from './index.js';

describe('sum', function() {
   it('should change from xPlayer to oPlayer based on if whoseTurn is even or odd', function ({

   }))
})
```

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="square" id="0">
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="1">
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="2">
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="3">
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="4">
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="5">
</div>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```

So basically there would be a switch between xplayer and yplayer that I would want to test to see if is happening from the click event

Comment: You want to know how to simulate a `click` event on one of the `square` divs?

Comment: Hi Maaz, yes that's right. Anther check I will want to do is to see if the div is filled as I would not want xplayer to override yplayer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you could simulate an event on a DOM element manually. That's mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events). It involves creating a new `Event` (`MouseEvent` in your case) and then calling `dispatchEvent` with it, on the DOM element you wish to simulate the click. It's pretty tedious and has issues cross-browsers.

There is a popular library called [`simulant`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/simulant), that makes this really easy. A click event would be as simple as

```
simulant.fire( target, 'click' );
```

where `target` is the DOM element you want to simulate the click.

A simple demo where I simulate a click on a button.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
const simulate = document.getElementById("simulate");

target.addEventListener("click", () => alert("Target clicked!"))

simulate.addEventListener("click", () => simulant.fire(target, "click"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simulant/dist/simulant.umd.js"></script>
<button id="target">Click me</button>
<button id="simulate">Simulate</button>
```